# Perception of value between different currencies

Tags: international-trade, currency, international-economics, price, currency-peg

So let's say I am going to sell a game and I'm trying to come up with a fair price.

The thing is, I am from Brazil and I'm selling in an online platform where most products are priced in dollars.

The brazillian currency is reais. Let's say that the conversion from dollar to reais is:
5 reais = 1 dolar.

And here's my doubt. If I sell my game for 10 dollars, it would be 50 reais for brazillians. And 50 reais for a game is kind of expensive from a brazilian point of view. But is 10 dollars equally expensive for someone in United States for example?

I am referring to this as perception of value. Is the value of 10 dollars perceived by an American equal to the value of 50 reais perceived by a brazillian?

And if there's a difference, does anyone have a tip on how to adjust the pricing in this context?

Comment: You might want to Google PPP (purchasing power parity) and the big Mac index.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Consider something like hours of average wage. The bare minimum wage in the US is about $7 so your game costs about 1.5 hours at most. But in Brazil the *average* (not minimum) wage is about 16 reals per hour, so your game costs about 2.5 hours on average.